# call activity through intent after view pager end

Tags: android

I want to call new activity through intent after view pager ends. Any help would be really appreciated so far i have tried on pagechange listener but its not working.

Here is my code.

```
 @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.viewpger);

        mCustomPagerAdapter = new CustomPagerAdapter(this);
        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mCustomPagerAdapter);
        mViewPager.setOnPageChangeListener(new OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
         if(position== mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount()){

                Intent reg = new Intent(MainActivity.this,MainActivity1.class);
                            startActivity(reg);
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    }
```

Comment: How is it 'not working'? What behaviour are you seeing?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you should decrease the getCount() by one, since the position will call 0 - 1 - 2 for a amount of 3 pages.

```
if(position== mViewPager.getAdapter().getCount() - 1){
...
}
```

Or what is your error?